# How to compare two tm (from ctime) variables

Tags: c++, date, calendar, date-arithmetic, gregorian-calendar

I've just started to learn C++.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with Visual Studio version:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.9.12
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.12+28307.665
Installed Version: Enterprise

Visual C++ 2017   00369-90013-89248-AA631
Microsoft Visual C++ 2017

Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake
```

I'm trying to compare these two dates:

> 1582 October 15
>   2009 June 19 18:00

Because I want to know if a date is later than 1582 October 15.

To do it, I have this piece of code:

```
#include <ctime>
tm date = { 0, 0, 18, 19, 5, 109, 0, 0, 0 };
tm gregorian = { 0, 0, 0, 15, 9, (1582 - 1900), 0, 0, 0};

double aux = std::difftime(std::mktime(&date), std::mktime(&gregorian));
```

But `aux` is equal to `0.0`. I think it must be different than zero.

Am I doing something wrong or the result is correct?

Comment: The `tm` structure cannot (reliably) hold dates earlier than 1900 January 1st.

Comment: do you have access to c++11 std::chrono::XXX ?

Comment: @OznOg I don't know. I have updated my question with more details about my Windows and Visual Studio versions.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Maybe I'm going to use another structure. Which do you recommend me? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to use c++11 and thus [std::chrono](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: @churill Chrono doesn't have calendar utilities until C++20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you work with *older* dates, you should be careful with the date and time functions you use.  *Older* may already start the day before [1970-01-01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  And if you go back to the 1582-10-15, that is the entry in force of the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar), then extra-extra care is needed.

### What's the problem ?

In your code, `mktime()` converts a date into a `time_t` that you then use to make the difference between two dates.   According to the C standard:

> The range and precision of times representable in `clock_t` and
>   `time_t` are implementation-defined.

Typically,  [time_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) is expressed in the number of elapsed seconds since 1970-01-01. This requires to know (or assume) the timezone of the date and time (by default 0:00:00), and to have a perfect understanding not only of the leap years but also the [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

[`mktime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) returns an error code of -1 if the date is invalid or if it cannot be converted in the time_t range supported by the implementation.  A safer version of your code would therefore check for the potential error:

```
std::time_t th = std::mktime(&date); 
std::time_t tl = std::mktime(&gregorian); 
if (th==-1 || tl==-1) {
    std::cout<<"At least one of the date couldn't be converted"<<std::endl;
}
else {
    double aux = std::difftime(th, tl);
    std::cout << aux<< " "<< aux/3600.0/24.0/365.25 <<std::endl; 
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/4NsCZy) with an implementation on which it works well. For MSVC, the conversion fails for any date before 1970-01-01.  It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mktime-mktime32-mktime64?view=vs-2019).

### Is there a better solution ?

Now if you go back in time to 1582-10-15, it does not make so much sense to convert this into the precise number of seconds for comparing two old dates.
You may therefore want to consider  [`boost::gregorian::date`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#date_time.gregorian.date_class).  This library is able to work with dates from 1400-Jan-01 to 9999-Dec-31.  Instead of converting into seconds,  it converts the date into a day count.

You can then reliably compare dates like 1582-10-15 and 1582-10-14, by getting the difference in days:

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
date d0(1582, 10, 15);
date d1(1582, 10, 25); 
date d2(1582, 10, 14); 

std::cout << d1-d0 << std::endl;
std::cout << d2-d0 << std::endl;
```

### Why are old dates so complex ?

Funilly,  in the example above you will see that BOOST will make a theoretical calculation. It will find one day of difference between the 1582-10-14 and 1582-10-15 ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1hJiqrmmc6aMVCPw)).

Of course, **we all know that this is absurd**, since the [introduction of the Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar) caused 4 October 1582 to be immediately followed on the next day by 15 October 1582.

Note also that such a calendar inconsistencies exist at other dates, depending on the country.  For Great Britain for example, according to wikipedia,  Wednesday, 2 September 1752 was followed by Thursday, 14 September 1752.

And finally, if you compare dates before the Gregorian calendar, you need to accept ambiguity.  Take for example 12 October 1492, the day Columbus put a foot in America.  It's in fact a date expressed in the Julian calendar.  In the Gregorian calendar [it would in reality be 21 October 1492](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus_Day).

### Any easier option ?

Now, `time_t` is a bit of a legacy. The C++ standared refers to the C standard for the definition of the related functions.

Modern C++ offers  [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) and the `std::chrono::time_point` type.  The problem is that for the time being, there are no usable function to convert to and from a calendar:  these will only come with C++20.

But if you just want to compare two old dates,  assuming there are no calendar inconsistencies,  you could just compare, the year, and if it's equal, the month and if it's equal the day. I know it sounds ridiculous,  but this will work without trouble whatever your C++ version and implementation is.

Comment: Now that C++20 is available, the data structure is [year_month_day](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day)?