# check a timepoint exist in a periode of time

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two `std::tm` time. In my program the user input `string` date and I convert them to `std::tm`

```
std::tm start_time;
std::tm end_time;
```

I have a third `std::tm`. This will input like two first time points.

```
std::tm question_time;
```

I want to check `question_time` is between `start_time` and `end_time` or not?;

there is a bad way to compare all necessary members of `std::tm`'s struct. is there any better way in `C++11`?

I only can use C++11.

ty

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683730/how-to-compare-two-tm-from-ctime-variables

Comment: thanks for your reply that solve my problem. and i found that i can covert it to time since epoch and compare them. @JosephLarson